# Wirecloud icon customization

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I'm working on FITMAN Smart-Factory trial 5 demo (http://www.fitman-fi.eu/), 
and i need to customize WireCloud logo icons to change them with the factory ones.

Is there any documentation on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the best way is to use the STATICFILES_DIRS and STATICFILES_FINDERS settings for overriding some files in your current theme. For example, if you're using the default configuration, you can add the following lines into your settings.py file:

```python
STATICFILES_FINDERS = ('django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',) + STATICFILES_FINDERS
STATICFILES_DIRS = (path.join(BASEDIR, 'static'),)
```

Take into account that the FileSystemFinder should be the first value of the STATICFILES_FINDERS setting, so things like `STATICFILES_FINDERS += ('django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',)` won't work.

Once updated the settings.py, you'll have to create a static folder in the same place where your setting.py is located . Every file created in this folder will override the one provided by WireCloud. In your case, the interesting files are:

- images/wirecloud_logo.png for the wirecloud.defaulttheme and images/header-logo.png for wirecloud.fiwaretheme and wirecloud.oiltheme.
- css/wirecloud_core.css if you need to change any CSS rules related with the logo.

You can obtain the original version of the file from the static folder at the root of the instance (that is the place where the static files are collected to by default). You'll need to run the collectstatic command if you want to update any overridden file:

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic
```

### Example

If your have a WireCloud instance at /opt/wirecloud_instance you can run the following commands:

```bash
$ cd /opt/wirecloud_instance
$ <your_editor_of_choice> wirecloud_instance/settings.py
# Change the STATICFILES_FINDERS and STATICFILES_DIRS settings and close the editor
$ mkdir -p wirecloud_instance/static/images
$ cp <your_logo> wirecloud_instance/static/images/wirecloud_logo.png
$ python manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: So if i followed standard install manual i should add my static directory into  "/opt/wirecloud_instance/wirecloud_instance" and there add images/wirecloud_logo.png and change any other images i'd like to, but leaving the same name and position under static directory.

Comment: hmm i tried to change images/wirecloud_logo.png setting the variable as above but i seem i have always the same logo. Do i miss anything?

Comment: Run the collectstatic command. Modify "/opt/wirecloud_instance/wirecloud_instance/static/images/wirecloud_logo.png" and rerun the collectstatic command. This time, the collectstatic command should update just 1 file (and that file should be the wirecloud_logo.png file).

Answer (score 0):

You should check into {WC installation dir}/static/images/

I think the one you may want to change is header-logo.png

Comment: Take into account that you will need to overwrite the header-logo.png file every time you run the collectstatic command if you use this method (for example when updating WireCloud)

Comment: yeah, that's why i asked if there were any "official" way to manage such a change. BTW it seems i don't have header-logo.png into /opt/wirecloud_instance but i have it into /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/wirecloud/oiltheme/static/images/